# use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, yarnpkg, detox

Hi I am trying to build detox to test my app. I am facing compatibility issue. My app runs with android versions 21 to 31. I get the below error when I run the command "`yarn detox build -c android`"

**Error:**

> > Task :react-native-midnight:processDebugAndroidTestManifest FAILED [androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0]
> > /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/5677f0d1d2fd33816116c626e2dd87f1/vectordrawable-animated-1.0.0/AndroidManifest.xml
> > Warning:
> > Package name 'androidx.vectordrawable' used in: androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.0.0,
> > androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1.
> > /Users/user/projects/MyWorkspaceapp/node_modules/react-native-midnight/android/build/intermediates/tmp/manifest/androidTest/debug/manifestMerger10963475594834660155.xml:5:5-74
> > Error:
> > uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.65.2]
> > /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/b7e25968130290bea6922f5b0f7f24b0/jetified-react-native-0.65.2/AndroidManifest.xml
> > as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
> > Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
> > or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
> > or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
>
> See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information
> about the manifest merger.

**build.gradle:**

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 31
    minSdkVersion = 21
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
//    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
> <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21"
>       android:targetSdkVersion="31"
>       android:maxSdkVersion="31"
>       tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the below line in build.gradle. It works

```
subprojects { 
    ext {
        compileSdk = rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
        minSdk = rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdk = rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    }
    afterEvaluate { subproject ->
        if((subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android') || subproject.plugins.hasPlugin('android-library'))) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
                buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
                defaultConfig {
                    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
                    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! But I had to delete the old app from the emulator first. Thanks

Comment: You deserve a couple of beers!

Answer (score 0):

Try building by changing the `build` command in your `.detoxrc.js` file like below by adding `app:` as prefix for `assembleDebug` & `assembleAndroidTest`

```
build: 'cd android && ./gradlew app:assembleDebug app:assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=Debug'
```

Ref : https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/2712#issuecomment-1458411754